# Couldn't get details of each restaurant on the productdetail page from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a dynamic routing for a ProductDetail page (each Restaurant has its own details that should be shown on this page). the routing is working but I don't get any data and I can't figure out the right way to get data from firestore by the Id of each restaurant.

**PS:**  the product details are rendering in the console but the problem still how to display to the detailpage

**ProductDetail.js**

```
import { firestore } from "../../../../../fire";

function ProductDetail() {
  const { productId }= useParams();

  const [product, setProduct] = useState();

  useEffect( () =>  {
 
   firestore
     .collection("Restaurants")
     .doc(productId).get()
     .then( doc => {
       console.log(doc.data())
       setProduct(doc.data());
     })
   }, () => {

 }
 );
 
  return (
    <div className="col-12">
      <div className="card">
        <h1>{productId.name_restaurant} </h1>
        <p>Price:${productId.Currency}</p>
        <p>{productId.email} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
export default ProductDetail;
```

**this my console : all details of the restaurant are returned**
[image]

**Still cannot return details on my page**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see your state name is `product` and the param name is `productId`. In the return you used `productId` which is incorrect.

As you are storing the data into the state. You should write `product` instead `productId` like below

```
<div className="col-12">
    <div className="card">
      <h1>{product?.name_restaurant} </h1>
      <p>Price:${product?.Currency}</p>
      <p>{product?.email} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work and I'm getting this error : **TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function** for the line                                   
       `const { productId }= useParams();`

Comment: If that's the case. How you were getting data on console

Comment: I 've solved that issue but still cannot display anything even after adding product instead productId   **Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'name_restaurant' of undefined**                                                                                                              **Ps**; data was displayed in the console

Comment: Add a ? after product like ```product?.name_restaurant```

Comment: Also do it for others. It check undefined

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as solve if it does. And upvote it